# Typing in text field in iOS version of trigger.io app causes everything except background to disappear

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile-safari, trigger.io

UPDATE #2
So we found out how to debug our application utilizing the safari debugger. For those of you interested, here's the link on how to do this:

http://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/

Using this, we figured out that our issue was actually related to CSS that we were using in our code. In our body class, we had the attribute "overflow-y: auto". Upon deletion of this line of code, everything worked again in mobile safari.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

UPDATE: Upon further testing. It looks like if I go to the web version of this application (hosted on our server) from the safari app on our iPad, this bug still happens. If I do the same on the mac version of safari though, then this bug does NOT happen. Hopefully this information might be helpful.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So we have a javascript hybrid application that's compiled using the trigger.io toolkit. Jquery, backbone.js, and marionette.js are use in this project. We just started testing on iOS devices.

Everything works fine on both the web / android versions of this app, but on iOS (both simulator and device), the following bug is occurring:

Upon loading up the application, on the first view, when you first tap into a text field the application freezes briefly. After the application unfreezes, the following error code is output into the trigger.io console:

_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)

_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

Everything looks fine, but then if you type more than one letter into the textfield, the entire application disappears except for the background view. You can tap out of the text field, and everything returns into view, but obviously this is something customers shouldn't be experiencing.

I've researched a bit, and some suggestions have said to try and edit the info.plist file. I've looked everywhere, but I can't seem to find this file. It's seeming like trigger.io hides this from the developer somehow.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what might be causing this issue or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So we found out how to debug our application utilizing the safari debugger. For those of you interested, here's the link on how to do this:

http://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/

Using this, we figured out that our issue was actually related to CSS that we were using in our code. In our body class, we had the attribute "overflow-y: auto". Upon deletion of this line of code, everything worked again in mobile safari.